# optimize the conversion function (string to byte)

Tags: arduino

Hy community, I'm writing a program with arduino. I have write a function that convert string in byte but it it occupies so much memory. My question is if there is a function that I can use and it does not occupy so much memory on my arduino. 
I post the code below.

```
byte strConv(String str)
{
  byte a = 0;
  char n = 2;
  char g = 3;
  char stringa1;
  char stringa2;

  char m;

  stringa1 = str.charAt(n);
  stringa2 = str.charAt(g);

  m = costanti (stringa1);

  if (m >= '0' && m <= '9'  || m >= 'A' && m <= 'F') {
    a += m;
  } else {
    a += m;
  }
  a = a << 4;
  m = 0;
  m = costanti (stringa2);
  if (m >= '0' && m <= '9' || m >= 'A' && m <= 'F') {
    a += m;
  } else {
    a += m;
  }
  return a;
}
```

and the second function:

```
char costanti(char n) {

  char num;

  switch (n) {

    case '0':
      num = 0;
      break;

    case '1':
      num = 1;
      break;

    case '2':
      num = 2;
      break;

    case '3':
      num = 3;
      break;

    case '4':
      num = 4;
      break;

    case '5':
      num = 5;
      break;

    case '6':
      num = 6;
      break;

    case '7':
      num = 7;
      break;

    case '8':
      num = 8;
      break;

    case '9':
      num = 9;
      break;

    case 'A':
      num = 10;
      break;

    case 'B':
      num = 11;
      break;

    case 'C':
      num = 12;
      break;

    case 'D':
      num = 13;
      break;

    case 'E':
      num = 14;
      break;

    case 'F':
      num = 15;
      break;
  }
  return num;
}
```

Can I reduce this two functions in a new optimized function?

Comment: what do you want it to do? convert the hex-value of a string to integer? like this: `convert("0x1A")` = `26`? If so, you could have a look here: [official arduino reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/toint/)

Comment: I have to convert a string in byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want something like this:

```cpp
char strConv(String str)
{
  if(str.length() > 2)
    return -1; // return something which makes sense to you for "invalid"
  return static_cast<char>(strtol(str.c_str(), NULL, 16));
}

String myString(26, HEX); // creates the string "1A" for you

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("String: \""+myString+'"');
  char val = strConv(myString); //gives you the 26 again
  Serial.print("int: ");
  Serial.println(static_cast<int>(val));
  delay(1000);
}
```

This prompts me the following:

```
String: "1a"
int: 26
String: "1a"
int: 26
...
```